# Is it possible to use the Python requests library to send Gmail only using the Google Gmail API

Tags: python, python-requests, google-api, gmail

Is it possible to use the Python requests library to send Gmail only using the Google Gmail API? I am trying to send Gmail with a python request library. But it ends up with an error 401. I want to know what is the proper way to send Gmail with Google Gmail API.

```
import sys
import requests
import base64
import sys
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

AccessToken = ""

params = {
        "grant_type":    "refresh_token",
        "client_id":     "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        }

authorization_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

r = requests.post(authorization_url, data=params)

if r.ok:
    AccessToken = str((r.json()['access_token']))

EmailFrom = "Test1@gmail.com"
EmailTo = "test2@gmail.com"

def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
   
    message = MIMEText(message_text, 'html')
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
    raw = raw.decode()
    body = {'raw': raw}
    return body


body  = create_message(EmailFrom, EmailTo, "Just wanna Say Waka Waka!", "Waka Waka!")


url = "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send"

header = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + AccessToken,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.post(
    url,
    header,
    body
)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your authorization code.  Where are you getting params.   Also please include the full error message and not just the response code. There could be a lot of causes for a 401 error the message will tell you what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example on in the documentation for [sending with python](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#python)  You should consider using the Python Client library instead of coding this yourself.

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you use same hash algorithm that is expected by Gmail API.
   It should be possible to see exact token they expect you to send. And try to use your hash algorithms for token you are trying to send them. For example, I always try to escape my code with terminal and trying to use separate code blocks before, to understand that it works as necessary, in blank python shell in cmd/linux terminal you use.
2. on Your Gmail API tab make sure you enabled all the necessary scopes. Probably the main problem is exactly with scopes. Faced smth rly similar when was working with Google Maps API

Also, can you please provide us with a bit more info, you fail on 1st request to`auth_url` also, or it doesn't work only for 2nd request?

Comment: Hey@Izuki13. Your response is greatly appreciated. I was able to obtain the access token from Google API, but when I try to send an email using Google Gmail API it shows credentials are missing.